# $facebook->getSession() in Facebook page iframe app/tab only works when app admin logged in

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I am developing some custom iframe/canvas pages (or now known as "apps") for a Facebook business page. For my purposes, I would like to pull the users first and last name that is currently logged in (and currently likes the page) and output it on the page. This script works just fine when I am logged in as the app admin, but when I try login as my personal account or a a couple of my friends account - it seems that $session is null. Why is this happening and how do I fetch a first and last name without having the user go through any additional authentication?

```
<?php
require_once '../db/connect.php';
require_once '../../lib/facebook.php';
$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
$secret = "***********************************";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => '**************',
    'secret' => $secret,
    'cookie' => true
));
$session = $facebook->getSession();
$me = null;
// Session based API call.
if ($session) {
    echo "\$session is not null!";
    try {
        $uid = $facebook->getUser();
        $me = $facebook->api('/me');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
    }
}
echo $me['name'];
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible ([reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/#tabs)):

> As with a Canvas Page, you will not
>   receive all the user information
>   accessible to your app in the
>   `signed_request` until the user
>   authorizes your app.

So you need the user to authorize your application first, this can be found [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/#auth):

```
 <?php 

     $app_id = YOUR_APP_ID;

     $canvas_page = YOUR_CANVAS_PAGE_URL;

     $auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
            . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page);

     $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

     list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

     $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

     if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
            echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
     } else {
            echo ("Welcome User: " . $data["user_id"]);
     } 
 ?>
```

After authorizing your application and getting the User ID, the process is trivial I suppose.

Comment: Any idea how I can do this without redirecting the user to another page? Perhaps a js popup?

Comment: @YevgeniyVanChuchin: Sure, check out the fb:login in the [PHP-SDK example](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php)